# jquery not focusing on input after modal is reshown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

So on my page I have this jquery code that focuses on the nearest input for each modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).closest("[autofocus]:first").focus();
  });
});
```

This works fine the first time I open the modal. However, when I click out of the modal and reopen it, it doesn't focus on the nearest input like I would expect it to.

Here's my modal code:

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new_section">New Section</a>
            <div class="modal fade item-plus" id="new_section" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add menu section</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5 class="menu-section-title">
                      <%= label_tag :title %>
                      <br>
                      <%= text_field_tag :title, nil, :placeholder => "e.g. Appetizers", :class => "input-lg", autofocus: "autofocus" %>
                      <p class="error" id= "menu-section-title-errors"></p>
                      <br>
                    </h5>
                    <%= link_to_add_association "Add", f, :menu_sections, "data-dismiss" => "modal", :class => "add-section btn btn-primary", disabled: true %>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Divs,p and many other elements are not focussed by default

you should add tabindex, maybe please try this

```
$(this).closest("[autofocus]:first").attr("tabindex","-1").focus();
```

but please check if thats a div

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to do the trick :\ I added tabindex to the modal divs and instead the focus appeared and disappeared after a second